# Spring data redis transactional support

Tags: spring, redis, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using spring data Redis with lettuce implementation. I need transactional support in my application and I have searched several posts but I am stuck at adding a data source for PlatformTransactionManager.
I have seen this post where they have mentioned how to add it [see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/redis-transactions.adoc). But I am not able to figure out how do I create a Datasource for Redis as the PlatformTransactionManager needs a data source.
Here is my config

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("host", port);
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
    return template;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
  return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource()); 
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    //This is where I am stuck.
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how should I create a data source?

> Note: I am not using spring boot.

Comment: As far as I see Redis does not provide interfaces necessary to get full support of a standard Transactionmanager. So you must connect the so called Redis-Transactions with the transaction-limits of your application by yourself. If you need full transactionality and also have a sql-dbms perhaps you should think about storing your redis-data inside the sql-database.